# projection matrix using A = QR

Tags: linear-algebra

in a projection matrix where P = $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$, if you allow A=QR where Q is orthogonal and R is reversible, P can be then expressed as P = $QQ^T$. I can follow all those steps, but I seem to also be able to come up with an incorrect solution, and can't figure out what rule I'm violating.

P = $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ and A = QR

P = $QR((QR)^TQR)^{-1}(QR)^T$

P = $QR(R^TQ^TQR)^{-1}(QR)^T$

at this point if we simplify $Q^TQ$=I then it leads to the correct P=$QQ^T$ but if we don't combine and keep going...

P = $QRR^{-1}Q^{-1}(Q^T)^{-1}(R^T)^{-1}(QR)^T$

P = $QRR^{-1}Q^{-1}(Q^T)^{-1}(R^T)^{-1}R^TQ^T$

P = $QIQ^{-1}(Q^T)^{-1}IQ^T$ = $QQ^{-1}(Q^T)^{-1}Q^T = II = I$

This is supposed to be the case when Q is square, but not all cases.
I'm pretty sure I did something illegal, but I can't seem to find where.

Comment: Is it $R$ or $Q$ that is supposed to be square?

Comment: Note that $(Q^T)^{-1}$ is not necessarily defined.

Comment: I know that this is very old, but isn't $Q Q^T$ also equal to $I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: you are inverting $Q$. Is this well-defined for nonsquare matrices?

Comment: ah that makes sense, the book i'm reading only had square examples. Just to make sure, if it is nonsquare, then Q will have a at least one column of zeros which makes the determinant of Q zero and thus not invertible. Is that all correct?

Comment: I know that this is very old, but isn't $QQ^T$ also equal to I? Given that $Q$ is semi-orthonormal?